# How do I get rid of duplicate rows in oracle based on certain data restriction criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11G and have 2 source data tables called RES and TES that I use to create new values for the 'CREATED' columns depending on the data rule specifications.

```
Tables:RES
Number
entry
name
by

TES
Number
Completed
Machine
On


SELECT DISTINCT RES.TES_NUMBER,
RES.NAME,
RES.ENTRY,

CASE
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(RES.NAME,'Created By','i') AND RES.ENTRY IS NOT NULL THEN RES.ENTRY
WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(RES.NAME,'Created By','i') AND RES.BY IS NOT NULL THEN RES.BY 
END AS CREATED_BY,

CASE
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(RES.NAME,'Created Date','i') THEN RES.ENTRY
ELSE TO_CHAR(TES.ON)
END AS CREATED_DATE,

CASE
WHEN TES.Machine IS NOT NULL THEN TES.Machine
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(RESULT.NAME,'Machine|Manual G/H','i') THEN RES.ENTRY
END CREATED_MACHINE_ID

FROM RES, TES
WHERE RES.NUMBER = TES.NUMBER;
```

I am trying to create new data values for some of the above columns depending on the above rules if something has a certain string in the NAME or if certain values are null.  The primary key is NUMBER between the two tables.  When I run this select is creates the new values just fine in the case statements but it can create duplicates because there can be multiple entries for NUMBER.  Here is some sample data from a query:

```
NUMBER  NAME    BY   CREATED_BY  ON  CREATED_DATE  MACHINE  CREATED_MACHINE_ID   ENTRY
458920  Machine JONS1 JONS1   13-Apr-11 13-Apr-11  B30ST5   B30ST5
458920  Created By   MARY DOE 13-Apr-11 13-Apr-11                                  MARY DOE
458920  Calc    BEN90 BEN90   13-Apr-11 13-Apr-11                                    0
458920  Created Date TWING2 TWING2 13-Apr-11 8/2/2010                          8/2/2010
458920  EquipName  TWING2 TWING2 13-Apr-11 13-Apr-11                           DELTA 45
458920  Calc    DANNY3S DANNY3S 13-Apr-11 13-Apr-11                       98


DESIRED DATA                                
NUMBER  CREATED_BY  CREATED_DATE    CREATED_MACHINE_ID                  
458920  MARY DOE    8/2/2010    B30ST5
```

My problem is that I only want to get the value for the first case statement requirement that hits, instead I get multiple rows for the 'CREATED' columns for a single test.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry for the sample data being a little messy but I need a rating of 10 to post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `number` is the link between the two tables, you need to use an explicit `JOIN` or at least a `WHERE` clause. Without either of them you create a **Cartesian Join**.

Add `WHERE res.number = tes.number` at the bottom of your statement